# at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException: model class is not mapped

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am new to SpringBoot. I am writing a project in SpringBoot(along with Hibernate)

while accessing the database, I am getting following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: HashMapping is not mapped [from HashMapping where consumerUserId=:consumerUserId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.dao.InsuranceDaoImpl.userHashExists(InsuranceDaoImpl.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.dao.InsuranceDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f257a089.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.dao.InsuranceDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87c1fe8a.userHashExists(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.service.InsuranceServiceImpl.checkInsurance(InsuranceServiceImpl.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.service.InsuranceServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$31bac4e9.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.service.InsuranceServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49b68a9f.checkInsurance(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.controller.InsuranceController.checkInsurance(InsuranceController.java:31) [classes/:na]
```

My `application.properties` is as follows:

```
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/INSURANCE_DB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext

#auth  protected here
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false

#Enable shutdown endpoint
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

My Application configuration class is as follows:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.clinic.Insurance" })
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Dao is as follows:

```
@Override
    public String userHashExists(Long consumerUserId) throws Exception{
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = factory.openSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from HashMapping where consumerUserId=:consumerUserId");
            query.setParameter("consumerUserId", consumerUserId);
            HashMapping mapping = (HashMapping) query.uniqueResult();
            if(mapping!=null)
                return mapping.getConsumerHash();
            return null;
        } catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception in userHashExists Dao", e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if(session!=null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The Model/persistance class is as follows:

```
package com.clinic.Insurance.persistance;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "hash_mapping")
public class HashMapping {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "auto_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "auto_gen", sequenceName = "hash_mapping_hash_mapping_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "hash_mapping_id")
    private Long hashMappingId;

    @Column(name = "consumer_user_id")
    private Long consumerUserId;

    @Column(name = "consumer_hash")
    private String consumerHash;

    @Column(name = "modified_timestamp")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Timestamp modifiedTimestamp;

    public Long getHashMappingId() {
        return hashMappingId;
    }

    public void setHashMappingId(Long hashMappingId) {
        this.hashMappingId = hashMappingId;
    }

    public Long getConsumerUserId() {
        return consumerUserId;
    }

    public void setConsumerUserId(Long consumerUserId) {
        this.consumerUserId = consumerUserId;
    }

    public String getConsumerHash() {
        return consumerHash;
    }

    public void setConsumerHash(String consumerHash) {
        this.consumerHash = consumerHash;
    }

    public Timestamp getModifiedTimestamp() {
        return modifiedTimestamp;
    }

    public void setModifiedTimestamp(Timestamp modifiedTimestamp) {
        this.modifiedTimestamp = modifiedTimestamp;
    }

}
```

Can someone please help where I am going wrong.

DO I need to define something like `<hibernate-mapping package="it.besmart.models">` as we do in spring servelet configuration. If yes how to do it in my existing code?

Comment: For starters stop using native hibernate. Instead inject an `EntityManager` in your dao en use that to create the query. You are now using plain Hibernate so you need to write an HQL not JPQL.

Comment: If you're using SPRING JPA, look into their CRUDRepository interface and should be injecting your entity manager so you do not need to worry about the hibernate setup.

On another note try give the full classpath name for HashMapp

`Query query = session.createQuery("from it.besmart.models.HashMapping where consumerUserId=:consumerUserId")`

Comment: on giving full classpath like  - `Query query = session.createQuery("from it.besmart.models.HashMapping where consumerUserId=:consumerUserId")`
It says
`WARN 26501 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter   : HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from com.thp.clinic.tataInsurance.persistance.HashMapping where consumerUserId=:consumerUserId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering where I was going wrong.

Add `@EntityScan(basePackages = { "youentitypackage" })` along with `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app" }).` This will look for your entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this mistake "Query query = session.createQuery("from HashMapping where consumerUserId=:consumerUserId");"When make a request to the database,need add "SELECT" your entity in table WHERE.... 
 
OR 
 "HashMapping" to "hash_mapping"  (class entity must be same name as database)

Comment: No query was perfectly fine!! Accepted answer is what was missing :)

Comment: Then maybe this annotation @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.clinic.Insurance" })  change to  @EntityScan(basePackages = "domain"),if you have repository class,then to add in Application class annotation @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your repository class")